# How to implement a client-server application using CORBA standards?

Tags: application-development

I have been working on CORBA for making the client-server applications, i have already made some but having difficulty when i use to implement my application using different idls on different server machines and a single client machine.
can someone guide me for further or have some idea about it or have some experience of using CORBA ..?

Comment: Also if you add the relevant code snippets or if you point to a public repository where people can look at the code, it will be easier to help you. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.jacorb.org/   seems to have a good rep.  I'm using Glassfish, personally, which is probably overkill..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe one of the most popular frameworks to work with CORBA in Linux was [Bonobo](http://developer.gnome.org/platform-overview/2.32/bonobo-corba.html.en), but as you can see from the link, it's been deprecated for a while in the Linux desktop in favour of [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus), so you might want to start looking into that instead.

Other than that, there are a couple of CORBA on Linux guides on the net, but **seem to be quite old**:

- [CORBA, C++ and Linux](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/CORBA.html)
- [Linux DCE, CORBA and DCOM Guide](http://linas.org/linux/corba.html)
- [Alternatives to CORBA](http://linuxfinances.info/info/corbaalternatives.html)
- [CORBA program development](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3201)

*Note*: as I understand it, Bonobo was a wrapper to provide object-like interfaces to CORBA. The CORBA Object Request Broker (ORB) itself was implemented with [Orbit](http://projects.gnome.org/ORBit2/documentation.html). This [online reference](http://www.calcifer.org/documentos/librognome/corba.html) describes Orbit's implementation of CORBA quite well, albeit it is out of date and written in Spanish.

Comment: i use OMNIorb for doing my stuff ! i will of-course use the links you mentioned over thanx